# Disabled Fields - Still Pass though non-disabled data - CAKEPHP 2

Tags: javascript, cakephp, disabled-input

I have a form which has many fields, I need to display some of them as read only / disabled for staff level users while admin level users can save or modify all fields.

I have setup the following javascript which shows the fields as read only however it doesn't pass any of the data though to the model, $this->request->data is a blank array with this javascript on.

```
<?php if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User.group_id') == 3) { ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

$('.adminOnlyField').attr("readonly","true");
$('.checkbox.adminOnlyField').attr("onclick","return false");
$('.checkbox.adminOnlyField').attr("onkeydown","return false");
$('.adminOnlyField').removeClass('required');
$('.adminOnlyField').removeClass('date_picker');
$('.adminOnlyField').prop('disabled', 'disabled');

});
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

I need the staff users to be able to see the data but not change it for these fields with the class of adminOnlyField, the rest they should be able to edit / update.

Thanks

I then though maybe when the submit button is hit I could remove the readonly and disabled with jquery such as follows:

```
$('.clear_ready_only').click(function(e) 
{
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.adminOnlyField').removeAttr('disabled');
   $('.adminOnlyField').removeAttr('readonly');
   $('#CardModifysaleForm').submit();
});
```

It doesn't seem to work though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabled fields do not pass thru `POST` , you are doing:

```
$('.adminOnlyField').attr("readonly","true");
```

which makes it `readonly`, and it can pass thru `POST`, but at end you disable the same field again by doing:

```
$('.adminOnlyField').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```

this line makes it `disabled` due to which it does not get `POST`'ed. So if you want to make it pass thru `POST`, make it `readonly`, and remove the following line:

```
$('.adminOnlyField').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue I am running into is readonly doesn't seem to account for select fields. The disabled however does. How do I get around this?

Comment: @sluggerdog for select fields you could do like:: use "disabled" attribute and add in a hidden input field that holds the selected value of select field, that way you can POST the selected data and disable the select field as well..

Comment: Yes that was my backup option however I was also wondering if I could somehow remove the disabled and readonly fields as the submit button is hit? I put some sample code in the original post that I tried but it doesn't seem to work.. Thanks